# Width of space character is inconsistent with custom CSS font

Tags: css

The width of the space character (char code 32) varies in my text. This occurs in Firefox and Chrome. You can see the difference between the fullstops and C's in the below screenshot.

[image]

Relevant CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "NewsGothDmBTWXX-Demi";
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/bluedot/fonts/NewsGothDmBTWXXDemi/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/bluedot/fonts/NewsGothDmBTWXXDemi/font.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
p {
    font-family: "NewsGothDmBTWXX-Demi", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

What I've tried:

- Checked that I don't have the custom font installed on my machine.
- The spaces are even when using the fall back sans-serif font
- The spaces are definitely the same characters (asci 32)
- Changing various properties like `letter-spacing`, `font-kerning` and `text-rendering`

Comment: Are you using `text-align: justify`?

Comment: No, aligned left. I'll add to my question because that's a relevant point.

Comment: This looks like `text-align: justify` though - maybe one of the parent elements has that? See [fontke font preview for NewsGothDmBTWXX-Demi](https://en.fontke.com/font/10096618/preview/).. enter your text there. Seems like normal spacing to me.

Comment: `text-align: justify` isn't used anywhere in the project. The text is actually centered, but displays with the same spacing issue as aligned left.

The preview on fontke isn't particular helpful with debugging as the preview is a server side generated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to `&nbsp;` being displayed wider than a regular space.

This was difficult to pick up on as viewing the source in both Firefox and Chrome didn't display the `&nbsp;` - I only picked up on this when copy and pasting from view-source to an IDE.